# Input variable with special characters

Tags: command-line, powershell, special-characters

I have some existing command files that ask for the password. These passwords are now system generated and may include special characters such as a pipe |.

```
set /p pw=Enter password:
```

When the set command parses the pipe, it ends there. Obviously, I need to be able to input and parse the entire variable.

- This must use standard Windows commands (batch) or PowerShell; no additional software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclose any use of `%pw%` in double-quotes, like this:

[image]

Comment: I solemnly swear that I tried that. But it works now. <headthunk>

Answer (score 1):

#### When the set command parses the pipe, it ends there

You need to use the escape character:

> `^`  Escape character.
>
> Adding the escape character before a command symbol allows it to be
> treated as ordinary text. These characters which normally have a
> special meaning can be escaped and then treated like regular
> characters  `: & \ < > ^ |`
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> Echo THIS ^& THAT
> Echo Heading1 ^| heading2 ^| heading3
> Echo The Escape character looks like this ^^
> ```

Source [Quotes, Escape Characters, Delimiters - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)

Comment: That won't work when using set.